# Access is denied when running a Python script from a command line in Windows 11

Tags: python, windows

Suddenly during steps running python scripts I got an 'Access is denied' when running a script.

```
E:\crs\bde2\src>C:\python27\ArcGIS10.7\python.exe validate_csv.py aims
Access is denied.
```

Just trying to start python with no script or using -interactive produces no response.
However starting an IDE (pyscripter) and opening the file works as normal.

I spent two days following up this error message on web sites changing system settings, ACLs, permissions, developer overrides, admin permissions with no result.

Finally today I worked through yet another list of system settings and the last one suggested that I validate the system files (all fine) and then uninstall the app and reinstall.
[https://windowsreport.com/access-denied-windows-11/][1]

Comment: I'd also strongly suggest an update to a halfway recent Python version. 2.7 is obsolete.

Comment: Yes but it is required to use ( also obsolete ) ArcMap. I use a dozen versions of Python and they are all a pain! Virtual environments make it worse, when you upgrade you have to rebuild them.

Answer (score 1):

It turned out that the startup python.exe in the install directory c:\python27 had been set to zero bytes!
All I had to do was to restore the file (27k) and it is working again. Nothing to do with the windows system message putting me off the scent.
I do not know how the file was corrupted, but clearly it was.